# Accessing Ethereum Dapp

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Is their a way to access ethereum Dapps other than the mist browser. I was thinking along the lines of a normal browser like chrome. Also, as a sub question how are some Android and IOS apps connecting to the blockchain?

Comment: Can I know more about your question ? whether you want access blockchain from android app?

Comment: Yes, how would I access the blockchain with android and also through a normal browser and not mist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that through Ethereum JSON-RPC: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

You have to use

- `eth_call` - read from contract
- `eth_sendTransaction` - send transaction to a contract

You must understand that you'll also need to have an Ethereum node started, most probably with *unlocked account* to execute transactions from it. Which means you don't want to run it on public networks, but rather in local network. That's what Mist do for you essentially.

Also, take a look at [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/), it provides same API for browser based app, but requires an additional plugin to be installed into a browser